# Node callbacks; else blocks vs return

Tags: node.js, callback, flow-control

I often see node.js programmers, when calling functions that expect callbacks, do this:

```
callSomeThing(arg1, arg2, function (err, data) {
   if(err) {
       // Handle the error case
   } else {
       // Proceed normally
   }
});
```

Is there any technical reason why they use an else block instead of returning in the error case or is it just a code style thing?

```
callSomeThing(arg1, arg2, function (err, data) {
   if(err) {
       // Handle the error case
       return;
   } 
   // proceed normally
});
```

Comment: How is that related to callbacks or even node ? It's just a common point of disagreement regarding coding style, isn't it ? Some coders prefer symmetry (first case), some other lightness (second case).

Comment: I had a coworker tell me that node would care specifically because of something to do with asynchronisity.  I tend to agree with you; it's just a code style thing -- but I was specifically told otherwise.

Comment: I prefer validate input params in the top of the functions with second style. It helps avoid a lot of if - else statements, and I always know, after all if, I have valid data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its just a matter of coding style.
But I would recommend the second approach, because its much clearer and reduceses the overall complexity.

Comment: It is cleaner since there is less indent, useful when a lot of nested callbacks.

Comment: When you nest a lot of callbacks, look for promises.